# Singular perturbation problem (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have found the following singular perturbation problem,

$\epsilon u_{xx} + |u_x|u_x + u = 0$, $x>0$;

with initial conditions, $u(0) = \epsilon^2$, $u_x(0) = 0$, where $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$. The question is to find an approximate solution $\forall x > 0$.

I am rather new with these methods and I have never found a problem like this (I have just worked with more or less basic problems where you can easily apply multiple scales method or WKB, for example), so I do not have much idea about how to proceed. Any hint?

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for a multiple scales approach, oscillations with decreasing amplitude, but the equations just don't seem to work nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Written as a two-dimensional dynamical system, the ODE yields
\begin{align}
 u' &= v,\\
 \epsilon v' &= -u - v |v|. \tag{1}
\end{align}
From a dynamical systems point of view, this system is a bit unusual since the vector field is $C^1$ but not $C^2$. However, that shouldn't be a problem per se. Since you're interested in an initial condition very close to the origin, in particular $(u(0),v(0)) = (\epsilon^2,0)$, it is useful to look at the stability of the origin. The eigenvalues of the linearisation of $(1)$ around $(0,0)$ are $\pm \frac{i}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$, which means the origin is a center. Therefore, we can't invote the [Grobman-Hartman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem) directly, but we see that the nonlinear term $-v|v|$ is attractive. Therefore, exactly as @David suggested, we expect an oscillatory solution with slowly decreasing amplitude. Moreover, the oscillation frequency is moderately fast, as it scales as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ (see the eigenvalues of the origin).

From the initial condition $u(0)=\epsilon^2$, we see that it is useful to introduce a rescaled variable $u = \epsilon^2 y$. If we wouldn't do that, and look for solutions of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ or $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$, the initial condition would just be $u(0)= 0$ to leading order, yielding the trivial solution $u = 0$. 
Anyway, in terms of $y$, the ODE is
\begin{equation}
\epsilon y_{xx} + \epsilon^2 y_x |y_x| + y = 0,\quad y(0)=1,\;y_x(0)=0. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Introducing the rescaled variable $\xi = \frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$, we get
\begin{equation}
y_{\xi \xi} + \epsilon y_\xi |y_\xi| + y = 0,\quad y(0)=1,\;y_\xi(0)=0. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Now *this* is an equation we can work with! Clearly, the leading order solution to $(3)$ is $\cos \xi$. But how to get an expression for the slowly decreasing amplitude?

The best way to approach this, I think, is to use the *method of averaging*. For more information, see F. Verhulst, *Nonlinear Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* (2nd ed.), Springer, 2006, chapter 11. To be brief, our ODE $(3)$ is of the form
\begin{equation}
 y_{\xi\xi} + y = \epsilon f(y,y_\xi) = - \epsilon y_\xi |y_\xi|.
\end{equation}
The solutions to the unperturbed ODE are $\alpha \cos \xi$ and $\beta \sin \xi$. Suppose we write the solution to the full ODE as
\begin{equation}
 y(\xi) = \alpha(\xi) \cos \xi + \beta(\xi) \sin \xi,
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{equation}
 y'(\xi) = -\alpha(\xi) \sin\xi + \beta(\xi) \cos \xi
\end{equation}
(we can always make this choice by choosing suitable $\alpha$ and $\beta$). Then, we obtain
\begin{align}
-\alpha_\xi \sin\xi + \beta_\xi \cos\xi &= - \epsilon \left((\beta(\xi) \cos \xi -\alpha(\xi) \sin\xi)|\beta(\xi) \cos \xi -\alpha(\xi) \sin\xi|\right),\\
\alpha_\xi \cos \xi + \beta_\xi \sin\xi &= 0,
\end{align}
yielding
\begin{align}
 \alpha_\xi &= \epsilon \sin \xi \left((\beta(\xi) \cos \xi -\alpha(\xi) \sin\xi)|\beta(\xi) \cos \xi -\alpha(\xi) \sin\xi|\right),\\
 \beta_\xi &= -\epsilon \cos \xi \left((\beta(\xi) \cos \xi -\alpha(\xi) \sin\xi)|\beta(\xi) \cos \xi -\alpha(\xi) \sin\xi|\right).
\end{align}
Now, we average the right hand side over one period in $\xi$, leaving $\alpha$ and $\beta$ fixed. This yields a system for the *averaged* values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, denoted as $\alpha_a$ and $\beta_a$,
\begin{align}
 \alpha_{a,\xi} &= - \epsilon \frac{8}{3} \alpha_a \sqrt{\alpha_a^2+\beta_a^2},\\
 \beta_{a,\xi} &= - \epsilon \frac{8}{3} \beta_a \sqrt{\alpha_a^2+\beta_a^2}.
\end{align}
We can solve this system easily using polar coordinates, i.e. $\alpha_a = r_a \cos \theta_a$ and $\beta_a = r_a \sin \theta_a$, yielding
\begin{align}
 r_{a,\xi} &= -\epsilon \frac{8}{3} r_a^3,\\
\theta_{a,\xi} &= 0. 
\end{align}
Thus, the general leading order solution to $(3)$ is
\begin{equation}
 y(\xi) = \frac{\cos (\xi-\xi_0)}{\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}\epsilon\xi + r_0}}.
\end{equation}
The initial conditions fix $\xi_0 = 0$ and $r_0 = 1$. In terms of the original spatial variable $x$ and the original function $u$, we thus obtain
\begin{equation}
 u(x) = \epsilon^2\frac{\cos \frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}{\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}\sqrt{\epsilon}x+1}}
\end{equation}
as a leading order, multiple scale approximation of the solution to the original ODE.

Comment: Very nice answer, I was hoping you'd see this question!

Comment: Thanks! The oscillatory nature of the solution really put me on the right track, though, so thank you for spotting that!

Comment: Until today I couldn't study this problem again, and it was great to see your answer; it has been a great help! Thank you @FritsVeerman and David ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this problem again, and I have found that there is a mistake in the solution. The ODE for $r_{a,\xi}$ yields $r_{a,\xi} = -\epsilon \frac{8}{3} r_a^2$, instead of the cubic term in the rhs. Also I think there is something wrong with the $\frac{8}{3}$ coefficient; I have applied a simple multiple scale method and the solvability condition gives me the following amplitude equation,

$$\frac{d A}{d \tau} = - \frac{4}{3 \pi} A^2$$, where $\tau = \epsilon \xi$. So finally the solution at first order is,

$$u(x) \sim \epsilon^2 \frac{\cos \left( \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} + \tan^{-1} \left( - \dfrac{4}{3 \pi} \epsilon \right) \right)}{\dfrac{4}{3 \pi} \sqrt{\epsilon} x +1}\, \, (\epsilon \to 0+)$$